# Network - only one PC can connect to Internet

Tags: networking, internet

Sorry for my English.

We have a network. For the last two weeks when any PC is downloading a file from the Internet other PCs cannot connect to the Internet. Looks like the router sets all the bandwidth to the connected PC.

I restored router's config file from 2013 and yet the problem prevails.

I have both LAN and WLAN connections because the network has 30-40 computers.
The router is Vigor 2700 series.

Any help or idea is useful for me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add more information to the question. What router do you use? How are the PCs connected to the router LAN? WLAN?

Comment: LAN and WLAN and the router is Vigor 2700 series. I added extra info to the question

Comment: Can you provide more details about the file being downloaded and the bandwidth allocated to your connection (as well as what specific type of connection it is)?. The router doesn't hand over all bandwidth to any given device, but must share it. If one machine is sending or pulling enough data to fill the lane, then other machines may have trouble getting their data in or out. There are sometimes settings in the router (QoS) where you can actually control order of packets that the router processes, so you can keep either certain machines, or certain types of traffic from clogging your pipe.